# php.ini on local machine not allowing values to be changed

Tags: php, bash, macos, ini

i am trying to change the php.ini on my local (mac)

i had the following file

```
php.ini.default
```

so I copied it to create a php.ini

```
cp php.ini.default php.ini
```

I now have the desired php.ini, however I am not allowed to make changes.

```
  :w! = 
  W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
  E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)
  "php.ini" E212: Can't open file for writing
```

I have also tried changing the chmod

```
chmod 777 php.ini 
chmod: Unable to change file mode on php.ini: Operation not permitted
```

Short of throwing my mac in the ocean and abandoning php entirely, how do i change php.ini values on a local machine.

Comment: Do you use sudo? `sudo chmod ....` and do you have a sudoer account?

Comment: You are probably not the owner of the file. You can try editing the file with `sudo`

Comment: disable SIP Make changes then re enable SIP https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481